# How to upgrade js-devel-1.7.0 to js-devel-1.8.5

Tags: linux, couchdb

I installed couchdb's dependencies `spidermonkey`,CouchDB builds against the default `js-devel-1.7.0` included in some distributions, it’s recommended to use a more recent `js-devel-1.8.5`, so I want upgrade this and I download `js-devel-1.8.5-9.fc17.x86_64.rpm`, I use `rpm -ivh` but has error and warning like this:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to show OS name and version. Besides that, please use `yum` for package install : `cd Downloads/` ... # `yum install js-1.8.5-9.fc17.x86_64.rpm js-devel-1.8.5-9.fc17.x86_64.rpm  --nogpgcheck` . Then the required dependencies will be installed too.

Comment: @KnudLarsen My OS is 'Red Hat 4.4',I used above command, but has new error message:'Error: Package: 1:js-1.8.5-9.fc17.x86_64 (/js-1.8.5-9.fc17.x86_64)Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows: automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch has missing requires of autoconf >= ('0', '2.62', None)libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of autoconf >= ('0', '2.58', None)', but my autoconf version is 2.68

Comment: RHEL 4 was released year 2005, and not supported for the last ~3 years.